# Переход на другой url с передачей токена авторизации

Tags: javascript, redirect

Пользователь работает в веб приложении, при нажатии кнопки получает токен авторизации, переходит в другую систему со своим адресом, при этом автоматически аутентифицируется во второй системе под тем же пользователем с использование токена авторизации.
Проблема в том как перейти на другой url и при этом передать туда токен.

1 вариант - передать токен в хедере, но проблеме в том что для window.open и window.location нельзя указать кастомный хедер.
Частично проблема решается через переход в 2 этапа - сначала идем по url во вторую систему через xmlhttprequest, передаем в хедере токен, в колбэке делаем переход на тот же url. После успешного бадания с CORS обнаружилось, что хоть аутентифицироваться во второй системе на первом этапе получилось, но кука с идентификатором сессии при редиректе на втором шаге теряется, что принципе и логично - на выходе вместо проваливания внутрь системы получаем страницу логина

2 вариант - сохранять токен в хранилище браузера в первой системе и поднимать его после перехода во вторую систему, но поскольку хранилище привязано к домену после перехода прочитать ничего не получается

3 вариант - передавать токен как параметр в адресе второй системы, но почему то мое перфекционистическое эго отчаянно этому противится

буду благодарен за подкинутые идеи по всем 3 вариантам и за свои предложения тоже

Comment: Чем же вам так не нравится 3-ий вариант? (Как по мне идеальное решение, единственное, что там 0 безопасности)

Comment: Всё уже изобретено до нас. Почитайте про OAuth 2 (в частности про Implicit Flow), там используется что-то похожее на 3 вариант

Comment: Почитал про Implicit Flow - согласен с вами - практически полностью 3 вариант